# show multiple annotation in map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

i am new to map view in ios sdk. i want to show multiple annotation in map view 
    using lat and long.basically all lat and long are coming from server side in 
    json format. i am parsing all lat and long and saving it in different array.
     but how to show all annotation at single time. i am able to show only one annotation 
    at a time.Below is code  for single annotation i am using,

```
zoomLocation.latitude = latmpa.doubleValue;
zoomLocation.longitude = logmpa.doubleValue;
annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = zoomLocation;
annotationPoint.title = @"masjid....";
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:YES];


[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

mapView.centerCoordinate = annotationPoint.coordinate;

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 1.5;
span.longitudeDelta = 1.0;
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
newRegion.center = zoomLocation;
newRegion.span = span;
[mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
```

Comment: go for the `for loop` for adding annotation to map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

```
for ( int i=0; i<[yourLatLongarray count]; i++)
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;

    coord.latitude=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[yourLatitudeArray objectAtIndex:i]] floatValue];
    coord.longitude=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [yourLongitudeArray objectAtIndex:i]] floatValue];
    MKCoordinateRegion region1;
    region1.center=coord;
    region1.span.longitudeDelta=20 ;
    region1.span.latitudeDelta=20;
    [mapview setRegion:region1 animated:YES];

    NSString *titleStr =[namesArr objectAtIndex:i] ;
   // NSLog(@"title is:%@",titleStr);

  MyAnnotation*  annotObj =[[MyAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:coord title:titleStr];
    [mapview addAnnotation:annotObj];

}
```

MyAnnotation.h is

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{   
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
   NSString *title;
   NSString *subTitle;
   NSString *time;
}

@property (nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subTitle;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *time;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c  title:(NSString *) t  subTitle:(NSString *)timed time:(NSString *)tim;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c title:(NSString *)tit;

@end
```

MyAnnotation.m is

```
@implementation MyAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate;

@synthesize title;

@synthesize time;

@synthesize subTitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c  title:(NSString *) t  subTitle:(NSString *)timed time:(NSString *)tim
{
   self.coordinate=c;
   self.time=tim;
   self.subTitle=timed;
   self.title=t;
   return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c title:(NSString *)tit
{
    self.coordinate=c;
    self.title=tit;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: MyAnnotation*  annotObj =[[MyAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:coord title:titleStr];
    [mapview addAnnotation:annotObj]; what is this??

Comment: MyAnnotation is a class... in this class we have to implement annotation title and subtitle...

Comment: NOw as per NAZIK need to add his code but its not working any idea? because all lat and long are so much far but i need zoomtofit??

Comment: ok thank you i have implemented this. workign good. now need to set zoom level so that all positon will see only on one acreen so that user need not to scroll

Answer (score 0):

Get all the latitudes and longitudes in array and go for the `for` loop as user1673099 said,

and add the following `zoomtofit` code for zooming the mapview to cover all the annotations in the mapview by calling the method,

```
[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:self.mapView];

- (void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView *)mapView {
if ([mapView.annotations count] == 0) return;

CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;
CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

for(id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) {
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;

region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;

region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Add `- (void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView *)mapView;` in your .h and then in .m file after the for loop(not inside) add `[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:self.mapView];`